# Ruby namespace etiquette and convention

Tags: ruby, namespaces, naming-conventions

If I'm writing a helper for an established library, should I create a `TheirLibrary::MyHelper` module in their namespace, or stay out and make my own `::TheirLibraryMyHelper`?

I'm thinking to be predictably consistent, libraries often have precedent for adding extensions to their namespace, such as `Spec::Rails`, which is a plugin of rails helpers for RSpec, in the existing `::Spec` namespace.

On the other hand, I don't feel I "own" the other authors namespace, so should I have any business adding sub-namespaces to it?

Comment: I'd call it `TheirLibraryHelpers::MyModule`. To be honest, the Rails way of interfering with over libraries and even core Ruby is not preferrable for third-party libraries (if not to say, exceptionally bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay out of their namespace (whatever you end up choosing to name your extension namespace) because that means you aren't going to accidentally collide with something they decide to do down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I noticed that the convention for "plugin" or "extension" gems are required as:

`require 'coolthing/plugin'` which corresponds to the namespace `Coolthing::Plugin`

while other projects are

`require 'coolthing-plugin'` which corresponds to the unique namespace `CoolthingPlugin`

Generally only those that are "official" are embedded into the original namespace. Those that are follow-on additions from separate parties should use their own namespace.